# How to update table schema when there is new Avro schema for Kafka data in Flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

We are consuming a Kafka topic in the Flink application using Flink Table API.

When we first submit the application, we first read the latest schema from our custom registry. Then create a Kafka Datastream and Table using Avro schema. My data serializers' implementation works similarly to the Confluent schema registry by checking the schema ID and then using the registry. So we can apply the correct schema in runtime.

However, I do not know how to update the table schema and re-execute SQL without re deploying the job. Is there a way to have a background thread for checking the schema changes, and if there are any, pauses the current execution, updates the table schema and execute the SQL.

This will be particularly useful for the continuous delivery of schema changes to the applications. We already have a compatibility check in place.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR you don't need to change anything to get it working in most cases.

In Avro, there is the concept of reader and writer schema. Writer schema is the schema that was used to generate the Avro record and it's encoded into the payload (in most cases as an id).

Reader schema is used by your application to make sense of your data. If you do a particular calculation you are using a specific set of fields of an Avro record.

Now the good part: Avro transparently translates the writer schema to a read schema if they are schema-compatible. So as long as your schemas are fully compatible, there is a way to always transform the writer schema to your read schema.

So if your schema of the records change in the background while the application is running, the `DeserializationSchema` fetches the new write schema and infers a new mapping to the read schema. Your query will not notice any change.

---

This approach falls short if you actually want to enrich the schema in your application; for example, you always want to add a field `calculated` and return all other fields. Then a newly added field will not be picked up, since effectively your reader schema changes. In this case, you either need to restart or use generic record schema.

Comment: I believe what you explain is correct for `DataStream`. `DeserializationSchema` will fetch the new schema to deserialize events. However, my question was for `Table` API. Table API requires a static schema when we create it. I believe the records will be deserialized by `DeserializationSchema`, but the new fields will not be visible to users submitting SQL. I presume, `SELECT newfield from MyTable` will fail.

Comment: `Table` also uses `DeserializationSchema` and everything is valid for `Table` API. However, in your example, you effectively have changed the reader schema. That's only possible if you re-register the table to update the reader schema.